# How to print a value in table after checking 2 conditions

Tags: excel, formula

I have a table with time on the left and number of houses on top. i want to print a value for a specific house in a specific time. i am using `vlookup` to match the house and the value but unable to match it with time. as seen in the screenshot the value should only b printed fron 12:15 to 12:45. formula i am using is `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I$10,$B$3:$C$3,2,FALSE),"")`. Can anyone help to point me in the right direction.

[image: screensot]
workbook is attached for sample.

[sample workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArYn8TW3_a3d4TpjhXTkHiA0ahXg)

Comment: its not clear... vlookup returns one value for one parameter... you're talking about a range...

Comment: so should i use some other formula ? or vlookup with combination of some formula ?

Comment: depending one what you need, if you want a 2d search, you can use vlookup with match, if its more complex or you need a quantitive result then sumifs works

Answer (score 0):

Try this in I11 then fill right and down.

```
=IF(AND($H11>=$B$6, $H11<=$C$6, I$10=$B$3), $C$3, TEXT(,))
```

Comment: thanks it works, but when the time crosses midnight e.g 11 pm to 12:30am then it stops working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `INDEX` of your table, once you know which row and column you want?

You can then get the row and column number from within your range by using `MATCH`, for example:

column number: `=MATCH(10,[housesRange],0)`

and

row number: `=MATCH([time],[timeRange],0)`

This can be combined with index:
`=INDEX([fullTable],[rowNumber],[columnNumber])`

Comment: thanks for the reply. question: as i have a time range, will i use 2 row numbers ? and [full table] in index formula is where i have to print the values ? because when i apply it gives me circular reference.

Comment: Apologies I think I misunderstood your question above, so this may not work for your situation - as MATCH will only return the position of the first matching element in the array, whereas I think you want all possible matching cells. I think a modification of @Jeeped's answer below may work best for you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for a 2 dimensional search of the table, you should use vlookup and match:

Let's for the answer's sake define the table range as

```
 A1:J10
```

the column number (house number) cell is:

```
I1
```

and the start time cell is:

```
I2
```

vlookup, does a search on a column and returns a result from the found row in a defined column

to find the column to return, we can use match, match would return the column number of a value, so in this case:

```
=MATCH(I1,A1:A10,0)
```

The last parameter, 0, refers to an exact match.

with a vlookup, we have the 2d search:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,MATCH(I1,A1:A10,0), 1)
```

Since the time is set as range, I defined the last parameter of vlookup as 1, so it will found the closest time to the search parameter

Hope that helps